# Showing that if a plane curve $L$ is always perpendicular to a fixed vector, then $L$ is a line

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am working on the problem

> Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function whose gradient is nowhere zero and satisfies $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = 2 \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$ everywhere. Find the level curves of $f$.
>
> Source: *Multivariable Mathematics* by Ted Shifrin, page 120.

I think I've mostly solved this, but I have several doubts about my solution. Could you please enlighten me about the dubious steps? Thank you!

**Partial Solution**

We see $$\nabla f =  [ \frac {\partial f}{\partial x} \ \ \ \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} ]^T = \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} [2 \ \ \ 1]^T$$ and $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$ is never $0$.  Let $L$ be the level curve $L = \{(x, y)|f(x, y) = c \},$ and write it in parametric form  $[x(t), y(t)]^T.$ Since the gradient is perpendicular to the level curve, we must have
$$\forall t: \ \ 2x'(t) + y'(t) = 0$$
so $y(t) = - \frac 12 x(t) + k$ for some constant $k$. Thus, we see that $L$ must be a $\textit{subset}$ of a line.

My questions are:

1. Can we prove that $L$ is indeed an entire, infinite line?
2. How can we justify that we can write the set $L$ as the image of $[x(t) \ \ \ y(t)]$ for some functions $x, y$?

Thank you!

Comment: Proceed to find $f(x,y)$, which is defined on *all* of $\mathbb{R}^2$, see the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example).

Comment: But any such line is globally parametrized and $f$ is constant on the entire line.

Comment: @TedShifrin Wow it's great to see the author himself :) You are responding to Conifold's comment and not to the question, right?

Comment: Nope, I was responding to you :P

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I will have to think more about this.

Comment: Note that the level sets are closed sets (since $f$ is continuous). Once you learn the implicit function theorem, it will follow that they are $1$-dimensional manifolds with no boundary. But all I expected here was a global parametrization of $2x+y=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Thanks for the response. I’m sorry but I am still unclear about certain things. If it’s not too much to ask, would you mind answering several questions?

Comment: 1) Is level curves being “1 dimensional manifolds with no boundary” whats allows us to claim that we can parametrize them?

Comment: 2) I still don’t understand why x(t) can’t be trapped between -5 and 5 for example, giving us just a portion of a line

Comment: 3) Don’t we need the function to be continuously differentiable to apply the inplicit function theorem?

Comment: 4) Finally, what do you mean by “all I expected was a global parametrization of 2x+y=0”? Do you mean finding the relationship between x(t) and y(t) that I found? Because if I interpret your words literarily, I would just say  (t, -2t) is a global parametrization of that curve.

Comment: I'm suggesting that in this case we parametrize the line $2x+y=c$ *globally* by $(t,c-2t)$. I'm not claiming that all $1$-manifolds have global parametrizations, although of course they have *local* ones. To "trap" $|x|\le 5$ you would need $\partial f/\partial y$ to vanish, say at $|x|=5$, but this is way beyond the scope of everything. You just check that the whole line is a level set and you're done.

Comment: For 3), it's very interesting. Terry Tao has [a blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/) about a version of the inverse (and therefore implicit) function theorem assuming not $C^1$, but everywhere differentiable with invertible derivative. Note that my hypothesis *did* include differentiability, not just existence of partial derivatives. But, again, off the deep end for this discussion.